# PostgreSQL array of elements that each are a foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, foreign-collection

I am attempting to create a DB for my app and one thing I'd like to find the best way of doing is creating a one-to-many relationship between my `Users` and `Items` tables.

I know I can make a third table, `ReviewedItems`, and have the columns be a `User` id and an `Item` id, but I'd like to know if it's possible to make a column in `Users`, let's say `reviewedItems`, which is an integer array containing foreign keys to `Items` that the `User` has reviewed.

If PostgreSQL can do this, please let me know! If not, I'll just go down my third table route.

Comment: There have been patches to add this feature to Postgres, see https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/ (2012) and https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAJvoCuuEgQ%2Bpjv02rjvQN4o9s4_H3HJMdZdQwss2b0c0-xagEw%40mail.gmail.com (2017). They haven't been accepted as yet, but hopefully one day.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

PostgreSQL is a *relational* DBMS, operating most efficiently on properly normalized data models. Arrays are not relational data structures - by definition they are sets - and while the SQL standard supports defining foreign keys on array elements, PostgreSQL currently does not support it. There is an (dormant? no activity on commitfest since February 2021) effort to implement this - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441059/3304426) to this same question - so the functionality might one day be supported.

For the time being you can, however, build a perfectly fine database with array elements linking to primary keys in other tables. Those array elements, however, can not be declared to be foreign keys and the DBMS will therefore not maintain referential integrity. Using an appropriate set of triggers (both on the referenced and referencing tables, as a change in either would have to trigger a check and possible update on the other) one would in principle be able to implement referential integrity over the array elements but the performance is unlikely to be stellar (because indexes would not be used, for instance).

Comment: You _can_ define a constraint trigger that would check that. But I'm not sure if it works reliably in all cases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  could you give an example about `reliably in all cases` ? You mean sometimes trigger can be failed ? Thanks.

Comment: @LuanHuynh: I don't recall the (technical) details, but the last time this was discussed on the mailing list someone mentioned that a corresponding constraint trigger might not catch all cases - but that might no longer be true

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just make a relationship table for them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you post an answer with an example of such a constraint?

Comment: does it increase performance somehow ? Or should someone stick to the third table approach ?

Comment: workaround / re-design: having a separate many-to-many table

Comment: Apparently, [sql:2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016) _does_ support this behavior. Unfortunately the standard isn't freely available, but you can see it referenced in both [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/ms-tsqliso02/ef50d8ea-b423-4ed4-ab1e-ae7b2882eb8b) and [PostgreSQL's list of unsupported standard features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html).

Answer (score 174):

It may soon be possible to do this: https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1252/ - Mark Rofail has been doing some excellent work on this patch!

The patch will (once complete) allow

```
CREATE TABLE PKTABLEFORARRAY (
    ptest1 float8 PRIMARY KEY,
    ptest2 text
);
CREATE TABLE FKTABLEFORARRAY (
    ftest1 int[],
    FOREIGN KEY (EACH ELEMENT OF ftest1) REFERENCES PKTABLEFORARRAY,
    ftest2 int
);
```

However, author currently needs help to rebase the patch (beyond my own ability) so anyone reading this who knows Postgres internals please help if you can.

Comment: very HOT indeed... `CREATE TABLE FKTABLEFORARRAY ( ftest1 int[], FOREIGN KEY (EACH ELEMENT OF ftest1) REFERENCES PKTABLEFORARRAY, ftest2 int )`

Comment: The patch is awaiting author to follow up. Until the feature is available, you will have to use trigger to check integrity which may be slow.

Comment: shame, it doesn't seems to have been included :(

Comment: 2020, still unsupported: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html

Comment: Per the [patch email thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAJvoCut7zELHnBSC8HrM6p-R6q-NiBN1STKhqnK5fPE-9=Gq3g@mail.gmail.com), as of July 2021 it appears that this "still requires some major surgery."  So we could still have a while.

Comment: If it's still unsupported, why these upvotes? Am I missing something?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Mostly because it's awesome. You might be missing how awesome this would be.

Comment: @JohnO It would definitely be awesome, but upvotes are really supposed to be for _useful_ answers and this answer isn't currently useful because the behavior it describes is still not implemented. As of right now, there is only one truly correct answer to the question: "you can't do it". (I upvoted this one too, but that probably wasn't really the right thing to do.)

Comment: @MosheKatz very true, this answer is actually misleading.

Comment: @Moshe Katz the answer is useful for me