# How can we create integer array type column in knex migration?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a table something like this:

Table: Deal
Columns: 
Id int,
deal int[]

Each entry in deal array references some other table id. How can we create the migration for the structure? Also, how can we create array column in knex for postgres.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [specificType](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-specificType) method for that:

```
knex.schema.createTable('deal', function(t) {
  t.increments()
  t.specificType('deal', 'INT[]')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, How we define references for each deal? For ex: knex.integer('deal').references('user.id')

Comment: You want to add a foreign key to a table?

Comment: No, In integer array, I want to add foriegn key.

Comment: Just chain `.references('user.id')` to the `specificType()` call.

Comment: Incase anyone stumbles into this. It's not yet possible to define references for such a column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054753/8126654) for more.

Answer (score 1):

```
knex.schema.createTable('deal', function(t) 
{ 
    t.increments(),
    t.specificType('deal', 'integer ARRAY')
})
```

One can like this aswell.