# PostgreSQL array of ids

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In PostgreSQL you can declare a column as an array

```
hashtags   text[]
```

Is where a way to declare an array of ids to some table(foreign keys)?

Comment: Also you could look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

If with "*to some table*" you mean foreign keys, then no: arrays don't support foreign keys.

Neither "outgoing" (ids *referencing* other tables) foreign keys nor "incoming" (ids being *referenced* from other tables) foreign keys.