# Postgres 10.5: how to link an array of integers to primary keys of separate table?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, materialized-views

I have two Postgres tables, `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`.

`TABLE_A` contains column `table_b_fks`, whose values are an array of integers (e.g. `"{1,2,4}"`), which are of the set of primary keys for `TABLE_B`.

`TABLE_B` has two columns, the primary keys and `text`.

My goal is to create a Materialized View which is identical to `TABLE_A` except that the `table_b_fks` array of integers is replaced with an array of `text`'s from `TABLE_B`.

Is this possible? It seems that [postgres does not support arrays of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key). Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, an array of integers cannot be formally concerned as foreign keys, though it can be easily used to join tables:

```
select table_b_fks, array_agg(name)
from table_a
join table_b on id = any(table_b_fks)
group by 1
```

[Test it in db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f92ceb751f81ad014606c6a17a2c5765)

Note that the example is a bit simplified, you need a unique column(s) in table_a to identify its rows (that can be used in group by).

Comment: For future readers, my actual use case an `id` column on each table, so the only adjustment required was line 3 `join table_b on table_b.id` ... and line 4 `group by table_a.id`. Thanks!