# How to create an array to store primary keys?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables (Users, Links and LinkLists) and I want to store user ids and  their link ids in an array. However, when I try the code below I get following error:

incompatible types: integer[] and integer

Is there any way that I can store user_id and an array of link ids in a table?

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id serial primary key not null,
    email varchar(64) unique not null,
);

CREATE TABLE Links (
    id serial primary key not null,
    name varchar(64) not null
);

CREATE TABLE LinkLists(
    user_id integer unique not null REFERENCES Users(id),
    links integer [] REFERENCES Links(id) -- problem here --
);
```

**Example:**

Users Table*

```
1 example@gmail.com
```

Links Table

```
1 google.com
2 twitter.com
```

LinkLists Table

```
1 [1,2]
```

Comment: When you reference a foreign key the types in both tables must be identical

Comment: @JaimeDrq I'm totally aware of that. However, I also know that it is possible to  create an array elements linking to primary keys. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't have foreign keys together with array. Storing the IDs in an array is not a good database design to begin with (e.g. you can't easily prevent duplicates in the array). Using a properly designed many-to-many table is the much better choice here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL array of elements that each are a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you do not need array data type on LinkList table.

You need only two foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE LinkLists(
    user_id integer unique not null REFERENCES Users(id),
    links integer not null REFERENCES Links(id) 
);
```

According to me, you do not need 3nd table: LinkLists

Define a user_id FK on links table and refer to users.

Or best approach, use a treeview table, including REFERENCES ownself

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it will be needed to have 3nd table. So your approach makes sense but can't we create an array to hold primary keys?

Comment: You should remove the `unique`. And add a primary key on  **both** columns.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do!
Just add a new array type field the users table. And define an after insert trigger function for users table.

And update array field by CTE.

I am using that approach succesfully.

Comment: do you have an example or can you elaborate on/explain this a bit more?  I find this interesting if you have it working but there isn't enough here for me, or anyone really, to confidently determine if what I try and what you've suggested are the same, which is important for debugging