# Sequelize define association on Array

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have two models in Sequelize as below:

```
export const User = db.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
});

export const Class = db.define('class', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  students: Sequelize.ARRAY({
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
  })
});
```

How can I define an association between my Class model and the user model?

I have tried the below but it gives me an error.

```
Class.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'students' });
User.belongsTo(Class);
```

> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: column "class_id" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the syntax

```
students: Sequelize.ARRAY({
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' }, // this has no effect
})
```

Should be

```
students: {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY({ type: DataTypes.UUID }),
    references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' }
}
```

This won't work either, because the data type of `students` (`ARRAY`) and `id` (`UUID`) of `User` does not match.

Also, with these associations, you are adding two columns on `User` referencing `id` of `Class` but you only need one

```
Class.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'students' }); //will add students attribute to User

User.belongsTo(Class); //will add classId attribute to User
```

if you want to name the foreign key column passe the same name to both associations, [by default `Sequelize` will add `classId`](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/associations/#one-to-one-associations), however if you configured `underscored: true` on the models it will be `class_id`

Here is a working solution

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true },
});

const Class = sequelize.define('class', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true },
    students: DataTypes.ARRAY({ type: DataTypes.UUID }),
});

Class.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'class_id' });
User.belongsTo(Class, { foreignKey: 'class_id' });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I don't understand how are you linking Class and User tables, students should be referenced to define the link. 
If I try this, it tries to search for class_id in User table

Comment: This will create `class_id` column on `User` which refers to `id` of  `Class`.
Here is the SQL output
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "classes" ("id" UUID , "students" UUID[], PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" ("id" UUID , "class_id" UUID REFERENCES "classes" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`

Comment: If you want to make `students` an array containing foreign keys to `User` `id`, 
it's not possible to define foreign key constraints on array elements, so you may not need
associations between your models.
see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key

Comment: Thank you for this link, gives me clarity on the subject.