# How to use array in a sql join and check if all of the array elements satisfy a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables, `activity` and `contacts` in postgresql.

An `activity` can have multiple contacts in array form, like this

```
contact Id = {23,54,34}.
```

I want to delete a activity only if all the contact Ids of that activity are deleted in contacts table and keep the activity if at least one one contact id is still not deleted.

`Deleted At` is column in contacts table to check for deleted contacts. I don't want to use NOT IN.

Activity table

```
id    contact Id 
-------------------    
16    {60,61,23}
15    {}        
5     {59}
6     {}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using an inline array instead of a proper foreign-key and mapping table? (See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key )

Comment: Your senior _should_ have changed it to a separate table. Is it possible to make DB design changes at this point?

Comment: if i could replace this NOT IN with a join that too will be helpful

Comment: This is a really bad design and the problems you have are a direct result of that bad design. And why are you using an UPDATE if you want to DELETE the rows in activity? Btw you should also avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: as the way im updating them they will not be fetched in result anymore.. anyways, problem is that 'NOT IN' and subquery. those are too slow

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `EXISTS` predicate testing `contacts` table with `activity.contacts` array:

> ```
> create table activity (
>   id int primary key,
>   contacts int[]
> )
> ```

> ```
> create table contacts (
>   id int primary key,
>   name varchar(10),
>   deleted boolean
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into activity
>   select 16 as id, '{1,2,3}'::int[] as contacts union all
>   select 15, null union all      
>   select 5, '{4}' union all
>   select 6, '{6, 5}'
> ```

> ```
> insert into contacts
>   select 1 as id, 'q' as name, false as deleted union all
>   select 2, 'w', false union all
>   select 3, 'e', true union all
>   select 4, 'r', false union all
>   select 5, 't', true union all
>   select 6, 'y', true
> ```

> ```
> delete
> from activity a
> where not exists (
>   select null
>   from contacts c
>   where not(c.deleted)
>     and c.id = any(a.contacts)
> )
> ```
>
> 2 rows affected

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9817e8fa2cb755b1d6c7a6fba3510610)*

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNNEST` to convert the nested-array to rows, then do an anti-join to look for broken references:

([An anti-join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-left-anti) is when you perform a `x LEFT OUTER JOIN y` with a `WHERE y.KeyColumn IS NULL` - this gives you the opposite of an `INNER JOIN` with the same join criteria).

```
WITH unnested AS (

    SELECT
        Id AS ActivityId,
        UNNEST( ContactId ) AS ContactIdFromArray
    FROM
        crmActivity
)
SELECT
    u.ActivityId,
    u.ContactIdFromArray AS Missing_ContactId_in_Activity
FROM
    unnested AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts AS c ON
        c.ContactId = u.ContactIdFromArray
WHERE
    c.ContactId IS NULL
ORDER BY
    u.ActivityId
```

> I want to delete a activity only if all the contact Ids of that activity are deleted in contacts table and keep the activity if at least one one contact id is still not deleted.

This can be done with a `DELETE FROM` using `WHERE crmActivity.Id IN` with a CTE that generates the correct set of *bad* `crmActivity.Id` values, via  a `GROUP BY` with the above query:

```
WITH unnested AS (

    SELECT
        Id AS ActivityId,
        UNNEST( ContactId ) AS ContactIdFK
    FROM
        crmActivity
)
WITH brokenContacts AS (
    
    SELECT
        u.ActivityId,
        u.ContactIdFK,
        c.ContactId AS ContactIdPK
        
    FROM
        unnested AS u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts AS c ON
            c.ContactId = u.ContactIdFromArray
)
WITH counts AS (
    
    SELECT
        ActivityId,
        COUNT(*) AS ContactIdCount,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN ContactIdPK IS NULL THEN 1 END ) AS BadContactIdCount
    FROM
        brokenContacts
    GROUP BY
        ActivityId
)
WITH badActivityIds AS (
    
    SELECT
        ActivityId
    FROM
        counts
    WHERE
        BadContactIdCount = ContactIdCount
        AND
        ContactIdCount > 0
)
DELETE FROM
    crmActivity
WHERE
    ActivityId IN ( SELECT ActivityId FROM badActivityIds );
```