# PostgreSQL: arrays of foreign keys?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table containing a bunch of foreign keys pointing to another table:

```
create table foo (
    hourly00 uuid references hourly(id),
    hourly01 uuid references hourly(id),
    -- etc.
    hourly23 uuid references hourly(id),
    -- omit rest
);
```

Admittedly, this looks silly (and I am lucky to have only 24 of such keys), but I have not found anything better.

In the meantime, I stumbled on [PostgreSQL documentation about arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) (I did not know about PostgreSQL arrays before).  I got an idea and I tried this:

```
create table foo (
    hourly uuid[24] references hourly(id)
);
```

which, of course, immediately resulted in an error:

```
ERROR:  foreign key constraint "main_hourly_fkey" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "hourly" and "id" are of incompatible types: uuid[] and uuid.
```

But then I got another idea — to ask about my situation on StackOverflow.  So my question is: does PostgreSQL provide means for doing something like this, i.e. for having an array of foreign keys in a table?  Is it perhaps doable with some PL/*?  Or perhaps with some other database system?  I am willing to do my own research, but I have no idea as to where to look.

Comment: I don't think that it possible. But you may use an array of IDs (integer I assume) and check if that IDs is valid during INSERT/UPDATE by using a trigger.

Comment: "*Admittedly, this looks silly, but I have not found anything better.*" - create an extra table consisting of `hour smallint CHECK (hour BETWEEN 0 AND 23), hourly_id uuid references hourly, foo_id uuid references foo, PRIMARY KEY (hour, hourly_id, foo_id)`

Comment: ""*Does PostgreSQL provide means for doing something like this*" - no, this is the main limitation of using arrays in denormalised schemas. You can do a lot with triggers, sure, but Postgres does not provide this out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL array of elements that each are a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key)