# add foreign key constraint to uuid list column

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table with following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE apartment (
  id      uuid         NOT NULL DEFAULT fellowship.uuid_generate_v4(), 
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  owners  uuid[]
);
```

Where the column `owners` is a list of UUIDs referenced in table `owner` with following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE owner (
  id      uuid         NOT NULL DEFAULT fellowship.uuid_generate_v4(), 
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  email   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

How can I define a foreign key constraint on column `owners` of table `apartment` to the table `owner`?

Comment: it is still not possible to do so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key

Comment: **DO NOT** use array columns to hold references to other rows. Use an associative (bridge) table; e.g., create table, `apartments_owners`, with columns `apartment_id` and `owner_id` having foreign keys to their respective tables and a unique constraint on the pair.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL currently does not support adding foreign key constraints on elements of an array type column. It is also not something that would generally be recommended as good practice in structuring your SQL data structure.

A best practice for this kind of many-to-many relationship is to use an association table. In your case, you can introduce an `apartment_owner` table that represents the relationship between apartments and owners:

```sql
CREATE TABLE apartment_owner (
    apartment REFERENCES apartment(id),
    owner REFERENCES owner(id)
)
```

Every time you want to add or remove an owner, you can just add or remove a row from that table. You can also get an apartment with all its owners as a simple JOIN query.

If you really want to return the owners as an array, you can simply do that with an array aggregate query:

```sql
select
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    a.address,
    array_agg(ao.owner) as owners
from apartments as a
join apartment_owner as ao ON ao.apartment = a.id
group by a.id, a.name, a.address;
```